# Inheriting the methods in Kotlin classes?

Tags: kotlin, class, inheritance, programming-languages

I'm still quite new into Kotlin, and my current project is to write a tiny programming language using it.
I've progressed all the way through lexing and parsing, and got stuck when I'm trying to interpret it.

What I need is a class that inherit from both

- A base class to tell Kotlin that the functions will definitely return an object in my programming language, instead of anything
- A class for the methods to avoid writing dozens of (operator) functions that duplicate from Int, Float, etc.

I figured the base class can just be an interface to avoid multiple inheritance which Kotlin bans, like this

```kotlin
interface BaseObject {
    val value: Any
}

class IntObject(override val value: Int): BaseObject, Int() {...}
class FloatObject(override val value: Float): BaseObject, Float() {...}
```

However the problem rises immediately. Int, Float, and many other classes are final and their constructor is private. This means inheriting them into my classes is not possible.

Is there any way that I can reuse the methods from Int, Float, etc. otherwise? I'm really not a fan of writing all the methods again. Alternatively, Do I have any other solutions in the implementation part, avoiding the problem completely?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First off, what you probably want for your interface is something like this:

```kotlin
interface BaseObject<T> {
    val value: T
}
```

which then means you can have your classes look like this:

```kotlin
class IntObject(override val value: Int) : BaseObject<Int>
class FloatObject(override val value: Float) : BaseObject<Float>
```

I'm not clear on how you want to use the objects where something like `myObj.value + myOtherObj.value` wouldn't work, but please let me know and I can update.